# gzuncompress base 64 gawk

Tags: bash, awk, base64

Guys i'm trying to make a awk script that would work on a csv file (read one, work on it, and write the output to the second file). The work i need to be done is ok, but i a have a table that i need to gzuncompress and bas64 decode (last - commented - line of code).
That's what i've come up with, but it does not work. Any ideas ?

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN  {
  OFS=FS=";";
  IMGPATH="/var/xxx/imp/";
  IMGimportPATH="http://xxx/img/imp/";
}
NR > 1{
  sub(/\r$/,"");
  fcount=sprintf("find %s -name %s* -print|awk 'END{printNR}'",IMGPATH,$1);
  fcount | getline fc;
  close (fcount);
  if (fc == 0) {
    print $1,$0,$(NF+1)=IMGimportPATH"brak.png" FS "197";
  }
  else if(fc == 1)
    print $1,$0,$(NF+1)=IMGimportPATH$1".jpg" FS "197";
  else if(fc > 1){
    $(NF+1)=IMGimportPATH$1".jpg";
    x=1;
    while (x < fc){
      $(NF)=$(NF)","IMGimportPATH$1"_"x".jpg";
      x=x+1;
    }
   print $1,$0 FS "197";
  }

 #}
}
#awk -v RS="" '$3=="sn::"{"gzuncompress(base64_decode)  -d<<< \""$4"\""|getline $4}{print $2,$4}' file
```

Comment: First, this is a gawk script, not a bash script. Second, please remove line numbers from the code.

Comment: Code which is not working like it is supposed to is not a good requirement description.  What should the code accomplish, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm not altogether convinced Awk is a good tool choice here.  Would you be open to discussing implementations in Python, Perl, Ruby, etc?